# See folder size breakdown in Linux?

Tags: linux

Is there any command that could show me the size of several folders in linux, perhaps ranked from biggest to smallest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others said, `du` is the way to go. But knowing the options to `du` is essential. Here they are:

```
du -m --max-depth 1 /foo /bar
```

This will give you the size in megabytes of the directories contained in `/foo` and `/bar`. If you want the output to be sorted, pipe it through the `sort` utility:

```
du -m --max-depth 1 /foo /bar | sort -n -k 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can pass:

```
du -sm /dir1 /dir2 | sort -nrk 1
#or
du -sm * | sort -nrk 1
```

The difference between the first and the second is that the sencond will pick all the files and dirs in the current directory and the first just the dirs you passed.

Comment: `du -s` and `sort` don't really like each other.

Comment: I have yet to run into some kind of problem with these lines in any of my commonly used distros: openSUSE, Arch & Ubuntu.
I concour that without the -m switch it would just mess the whole thing. =p

Comment: Oh god! Sorry. I somehow mixed up `-s` and `-h`. Please disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1):

> du [options] [directories and/or files]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a graphical (X11) display, consider installing **`xdiskusage`**.  You can either pipe the output of `du` into it (as you might do if you're running `du` as another user, or on another system, or at another time), or you can run it interactively and it will invoke `du` for itself.

As usual, once it's installed, consult the man page.

Answer (score 0):

use `du` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line I prefer to list the biggest last so I use:

```
du -shm ./* | sort -n
```